# Can static/dynamic/const/reinterpret_cast be used in unevaluated context?

Tags: c++, casting, c++14, c++17

I tried to provide structures for checking is `A` is (choose cast)-castable to `B`. 
All four casts would have exact same implementation, expect their names (local-macro-able definitions would be possible, but not necessary). I wrote many check-for operators structures, for example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>

template<class, class, class, class = void>
struct is_valid_ternary_operator : std::false_type
{ };

template<class T, class S, class R>
struct is_valid_ternary_operator <T, S, R, 
                                  std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>() ?
                                                       std::declval<S>() :
                                                       std::declval<R>())>> : std::true_type
{ };

int main()
{
                                          //true? 1 : 0 //is ok
    std::cout << is_valid_ternary_operator<bool, int, int>::value << std::endl;
                                          //true? 1 : std::string("0") //would be error
    std::cout << is_valid_ternary_operator<bool, int, std::string>::value << std::endl;
                                          //true? std::string("1") : std::string("0") //ok
    std::cout << is_valid_ternary_operator<bool, std::string, std::string>::value << std::endl;
                                          //std::string("1")? 1 : 0 //error
    std::cout << is_valid_ternary_operator<std::string, int, int>::value << std::endl;
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f3bceabfe478caaf)

Expected output is displayed. But now consider doing the same with casts:

```
template<class T, class S, class = void>
struct is_static_cast_able : std::false_type
{ };

template<class T, class S>
struct is_static_cast_able<T, S, 
                           std::void_t<decltype(static_cast<std::declval<S>()>
                                                           (std::declval<T>()))>> : std::true_type
{ };
```

But it generates errors:

```
main.cpp:12:84: error: template argument 1 is invalid
    (std::declval<T>()))>> : std::true_type
                        ^~
main.cpp:12:94: error: template argument 3 is invalid
    (std::declval<T>()))>> : std::true_type
                                  ^~~~~~~~~
```

[Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cb4401c17fbb1812)

Is using casts in unevaluated context not allowed?

Comment: `static_cast` expects a *type* inside the `<>` brackets.  `std::declval<S>()` is an *expression*.  You seem to want just `static_cast<S>(std::declval<T>())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is using casts in unevaluated context not allowed?

Short answer: yes, it is allowed.

---

Anyway, I would try to reduce the example to a minimal, working one.
Note that *casts* are *expressions* and they are expected to work with operators the operands of which are unevaluated (`sizeof`, `noexcept`, `decltype`, `typeid`), unless explicitly stated the opposite.

As an example, `sizeof` is an unevaluated context:

```
int main() {
    unsigned int i;
    sizeof(static_cast<int>(i));
}
```

Far easier an example, and it works.
The same can be shown using `decltype`, the operands of which are unevaluated as well:

```
int main() {
    unsigned int i;
    decltype(static_cast<int>(i)) j = i;
}
```

And so on, we can do something similar both with `noexcept`:

```
int main() {
    unsigned int i;
    bool b = noexcept(static_cast<int>(i));
}
```

And with `typeid`:

```
#include <typeinfo>

int main() {
    unsigned int i;
    auto b = typeid(static_cast<int>(i)).name();
}
```

Comment: Well, no point to make new question since it does work im my code :) Thanks for enlightenment.

Answer (score 2):

`is_static_castable<T, S>` sounds like something already existing in the C++ standard library. as [`std::is_convertible`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_convertible).

And to your question: `static_cast` doesn't always mean compile time. For example, in the conversions of integer and floating point types, the compiler may chose to emit code for the conversion if it cannot do so at compile-time. Though. it can very much appear in an unevaluated context.

Unevaluated operands in C++ are very limited:
The contexts are:

- `decltype`
- `sizeof`
- `typeid`
- `noexcept`

To quote C++ standard draft, [[expr/8]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr#8)

> In some contexts, unevaluated operands appear (`[expr.typeid]`,
>   `[expr.sizeof]`, `[expr.unary.noexcept]`, `[dcl.type.simple]`). An
>   unevaluated operand is not evaluated. An unevaluated operand is
>   considered a full-expression.

---

NOTE: `std::is_convertible` doesn't cover all cases of `static_cast`

Therefore, for completeness, this is what you want to do with `is_static_cast_able`, covering virtually all cases of `static_cast`:

```
template<class T, class S, class = void>
struct is_static_cast_able : std::false_type
{ };

template<class T, class S>
struct is_static_cast_able<T, S,
        std::enable_if_t<
            std::is_convertible<T, S>::value ||
            std::is_base_of<std::decay_t<T>, std::decay_t<S>>::value ||
            std::is_base_of<std::decay_t<S>, std::decay_t<T>>::value ||
            std::is_base_of<std::remove_pointer_t<T>, std::remove_pointer_t<S>>::value ||
            std::is_base_of<std::remove_pointer_t<S>, std::remove_pointer_t<T>>::value ||
            (std::is_same<T, void*>::value && std::is_pointer<S>::value) ||
            (std::is_same<S, void*>::value && std::is_pointer<T>::value)
        >
    >
: std::true_type { };
```

The following test code passes:

```
struct A {};
struct B : public A {};

int main()
{
    static_assert(is_static_cast_able<int, char>::value, "");
    static_assert(is_static_cast_able<double, int>::value, "");
    static_assert(is_static_cast_able<int, double>::value, "");
    static_assert(is_static_cast_able<void*, double*>::value, "");
    static_assert(is_static_cast_able<double*, void*>::value, "");
    static_assert(is_static_cast_able<B, A>::value, "");
    static_assert(is_static_cast_able<A, B>::value, "");
    static_assert(is_static_cast_able<B&, A&>::value, "");
    static_assert(is_static_cast_able<B*, A*>::value, "");
    static_assert(is_static_cast_able<A&, B&>::value, "");
    static_assert(is_static_cast_able<A*, B*>::value, "");
}
```

See it [Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f31fcca7d33fc50f)